# Why isn't my Swiper slider working in Django?

Tags: javascript, html, django, image-gallery, swiper.js

So far, setting up Swiper has been a breeze. All the images load perfectly into the container, and the console logs no errors.

But while the navigation buttons show up and are clickable, they don't actually work. Neither does the clicking and dragging them. The console shows that all the images are loaded.

Other people had similar problems, and the fix that worked was adding:

```
observer: true,
observeParents: true,
```

To the initialization code, which hasn't made a difference for me.

Here's my HTML code

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swiper/css/swiper.min.css">
</head>
<div class="swiper-container gallery-top">
            <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                {% for image in car.image_set.all %}
                    <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="{{ image.image.url }}" style="width: 100%; "></div>
                {% endfor %}
                <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
                <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
            </div>    
        </div>
    </div>

...

<script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper/js/swiper.min.js"></script>
...
<script>
    var galleryTop = new Swiper('.gallery-top', {
        spaceBetween: 10,
        loop:true,
        loopedSlides: 5, //looped slides should be the same
        navigation: {
        nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
        prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
        },
        observer: true, 
        observeParents: true,
        observeSlideChildren: true,
    });
</script>
```

**Update**

Thanks to Pratik's feedback, I've updated the js, but Swiper still isn't navigating the images. There are no console errors, it just seems dead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's working for me, you can check below the working example.

```js
  var galleryTop = new Swiper('.gallery-top', {
        spaceBetween: 10,
        loop:true,
        loopedSlides: 5, //looped slides should be the same
        navigation: {
        nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
        prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
        },
        observer: true, 
        observeParents: true,
        observeSlideChildren: true
    });
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swiper/css/swiper.min.css">
    <title>Swiper Slider</title>
  </head>
  <body>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="swiper-container gallery-top">
            <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                    <div class="swiper-slide">
                      <img src="http://www.placebear.com/700/500" style="width: 100%; ">
                    </div>
                    <div class="swiper-slide">
                      <img src="http://www.placebear.com/700/500" style="width: 100%; ">
                    </div>
                    <div class="swiper-slide">
                      <img src="http://www.placebear.com/700/500" style="width: 100%; ">
                    </div>
                    <div class="swiper-slide">
                      <img src="http://www.placebear.com/700/500" style="width: 100%; ">
                    </div>
            </div>    
            <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
            <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper/js/swiper.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've just tried this code in its own file, it works perfectly. Yet the one in my project still isn't functioning.

Comment: I thought it would be a problem with my images, but I linked to the same placebear ones you did, and it still seems frozen. Could this be a Django issue?

Comment: Solved it! I had initially put the initialization code outside the body, but I just put it right below the other <script> tags and it works perfectly. Thanks for all your help, buddy. I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 3):

**Observer** and **ObserveParents** are not a part of navigations.
So Update your script with the below code.

`<script>
    var galleryTop = new Swiper('.gallery-top', {
        spaceBetween: 10,
        loop:true,
        loopedSlides: 5, //looped slides should be the same
        navigation: {
        nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
        prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
        },
        observer: true, 
        observeParents: true,
        observeSlideChildren: true
    });
</script>`

** This is the rendered HTML**

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swiper/css/swiper.min.css">
</head>

...
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="swiper-container gallery-top">
            <div class="swiper-wrapper">

                    <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="/media/image_11.JPG" style="width: 100%; "></div>

                    <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="/media/image_12_YQm2sd3.JPG" style="width: 100%; "></div>

                    <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="/media/image_19.JPG" style="width: 100%; "></div>

                    <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="/media/image_16_pm7OKF2.JPG" style="width: 100%; "></div>

            </div>    
            <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
            <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
...
    <!--  JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper/js/swiper.min.js"></script>

  </body>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, Pratik. But the image navigation still isn't working. Is there any other issue you can see in my code?

Comment: `<div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
<div class="swiper-button-next"></div>`
Swiper Navigation button should outside the swiper-wrapper div.

Comment: Tried it, the buttons are still inactive. I'm wondering if there's an extra set-up step that's not in the tutorial (https://swiperjs.com/get-started/).

Comment: Can you please edit your question and put the rendered HTML instead of the blade code?

Comment: Done! I've added the final version straight from Chrome.